# How to auth to execute a function only every X second in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, authorization, timeout, setinterval

So i want to execute a function by click on a btn `<a></a>`.
But I want to authorize the execution of the function only X seconds after having executed it the first time.
That my code :

- HTML

```
<a onclick="skipCard('left')"></a>
```

- Javascript

```
function skipCard(direction=['left', 'right']) {
    if(direction == 'left') {
        console.log('go left')
    } else if (direction == 'right') {
        console.log('go right')
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, that's called debouncing, look it up

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for but I cannot understand how it works

Comment: The basic way is to have a boolean variable, like `let canExecute = true;` Whenever you execute your function, you set it to `false`, and you create a timeout to set it back to `true`  after a few seconds. While the value is false, the function will have to return without doing anything.

Comment: - "Can you write the whole code for me please?" - "I could but that's not the point, the point is you give it a go and try it yourself, I already gave you a good hint." Really it's just about playing with a `true/false` variable and adding a timeout.

Comment: function debounce_leading(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    if (!timer) {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = undefined;
    }, timeout);
  };
}

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't want you to send me the code, it's just that I found a function that does the "deboucing" but I'm not asking how it worked. It was this one: